# How can I access an Interbase (.IB) database using pure JDBC?

Tags: java, database, jdbc, database-connection, interbase

I have a .IB file which I'd like to access using a Java Application. Where can I find the drivers for Interbase. My OS is Mac OS X

Answer (score 2):

In Interbase install

http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/interbase/IB2009/2009Update3/DevGuide.pdf

Chapter "Programming with JDBC"

Comment: Right, IB includes a Type 4 JDBC driver